# Run webpack build during docker-compose build process

Tags: docker, npm, webpack, docker-compose, npm-install

I am trying to build a production docker container with a minified version of the js files.

In my `Dockerfile`, after installing the npm packages, I am trying to build the webpack compilation.

```
RUN npm install -g n  # upgrading the npm version
RUN n stable
ADD ./webpack/package.json /package.json
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm run build-production  # <<< Fails here
```

The docker build process will fail during the last command `RUN npm run build-production` with npm complaining that it can't find the installed packages (`NODE_PATH` is set).

However, when I add the call `npm run build-production` to my `ENTRYPOINT` script, it works fine and compiles everything as expected. However, it runs the webpack build everything I start the container, which isn't desired.

Why can't the last docker build step find the packages installed in the previous steps? But why does it work through the entrypoint script?

What is the best way to add the webpack build to the docker build in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Could you include the exact error message that you get?  Is it possible that one of he dependencies for `build-production` is listed under the `devDependencies` which is why it can't find it ? It's not being installed because of the `--production` flag? At runtime do you use a volume?

Comment: @dnephin Thank you for your suggestion. All packages are included in the `--production` dependencies. I also get the same error without `--production`. Yes, I am using a volume. Isn't it accessible during the build?

Comment: No, volumes are not accessible during the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use

```
RUN bash -l -c 'npm run build-production'
```

instead of your

```
RUN npm run build-production  # <<< Fails here
```

this should help

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that `build-production` requires a `devDependencies`, which are not being installed.

A great way to keep your production images small is to use a tool like [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/). It makes it easy to run the build tasks in a dev container, then pack everything into a production image, all with a single command.

Below is an example `dobi.yaml` that might work for you.

```
meta:
  project: some-project-name

image=builder:
  image: myproject-dev
  context: dockerfiles/
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.build

image=production:
  image: user/prod-image-name
  context: .
  depends: [build]

mount=source:
  bind: .
  path: /code

run=build:
  use: builder
  mounts: [source]
  command: "npm run build-production"
  artifact: path/to/minified/assets
```

Running `dobi production` will run any of the tasks that are stale. If none of the source files have changed the tasks are skipped.  The `depends: [build]` ensures that the build step always runs first.